# Email link not working on Android

Tags: android, html, email, hyperlink

I have the code for a click to email link in HTML and it works fine on my pc but doesn't work on mobile devices (I only have Android so I don't know if the problem is only on Android or all mobile devices). When I press the link the browser says:

> Webpage not available. "mailto:ar1speed@yahoo.com?subject=Mileage%20%20%20&body="Todays%20date:%0D%0ABusiness%20Mileage:%0D%0ADid%20you%20have%20a%20business%20passenger?%0D%0AAdditional%20details:" might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem it is vital that the Click to send email link works.

My code is below:

```
<p>
   <a href="mailto:ar1speed@yahoo.com?subject=Mileage&body="Todays date:%0D%0ABusiness Mileage:%0D%0ADid you have a business passenger%0D%0AAdditional details:">
       Click to send email
   </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an [issue with Android OS](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63538):

> #### Issue 63538:    Mailto links are parsed incorrectly, entered entirely into the address field
>
> Devices Confirmed: Nexus 4 (two devices tested)
> Android Version: 4.4.2 only (tested in 4.3 and 4.4.0)
>
> Bug details:
>
> Mailto links are entirely entered into the address field instead of being parsed into Address, Subject and Body. Screenshot is attached showing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `mailto` which works just fine on mobile, so you must've just formed your URL incorrectly (check your ""s).

[MAILTO Link in email to start a new email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677963/mailto-link-in-email-to-start-a-new-email?rq=1)

Comment: Do I have to change it from a link. Also, do I just paste this into my code in the place of my email link code in order to get it to work?

Comment: It's probably easier to change it for a button, and just place the above code in the OnClick() method.

Comment: @user2627595 Hang on, I misunderstood. Updated answer.

Comment: @user2627595 My old code was assuming you were doing it from inside an Android application (my mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Your application need access for mail related apps.This can be achieved 
by adding following piece of code in

config.xml

```
<access origin="mailto://*" launch-external="true" />
```

then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to invoke the mailing applications in mobile and set the subject, and body of email as well.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:yourmailid@somedomain.com"));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");

                try {
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText("No email client found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Refer [Send Email Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701634/send-email-intent)
 for examples