# HTML Bootstrap Submit button not working on android devices

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap, form-submit

I have a web app that's doing a mailto action on a click action.  It seems to work on all platforms, except for android in chrome.  It even works in the developer console (desktop) with android devices.  The button is clickable, but no actions occur on android devices.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

```
<form role="form" action="MAILTO:info@somewebsite.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="InputEmail">Your Email</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" required  >
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
                                <div class="input-group"
                                >
                                    <textarea name="Message" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="form-control-feedback"></i></span></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email link not working on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045604/email-link-not-working-on-android)

Comment: thanks for the link.  This issue doesn't seem related to a specific link & formatting as much as the button doing nothing on click.  It should be bringing up an email client.